# Find the probability a bag contains m nails

Tags: probability

A worker carries two bags. Each of the bags initially contains *N* nails. Whenever the worker needs a nail, he takes it from a bag picked at random. At some point the worker picks an empty bag. Find the probability that the other bag contains exactly *m* nails.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: how many nails were taken if the non-empty bag contains $m$ nails?

Comment: Perhaps this will help :) [The worker with two bags problem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3678308/the-worker-with-two-bags-problem)